# Google Sheets error 400 "exceeds grid limits"

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to get a JSON body for a sheet using Chrome for now, but to be incorporated in a python script.

[https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[spreadsheet_id]/values/[tab_name]?alt=json&key=[api_key]](https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/%5Bspreadsheet_id%5D/values/%5Btab_name%5D?alt=json&key=%5Bapi_key%5D)

The sheet contains 56 rows and 6 columns, but I get the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Range ('tab_name'!TAB_NAME) exceeds grid limits. Max rows: 994, max columns: 26",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I was thinking it did not like the alt=json anymore, but I get the same error with just the key on the end.

Answer (score 0):

### A proper range is not defined

I assume you are trying to get values from a Sheet, as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) the proper way to use this endpoint is `GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}` you defined [tab_name] as part of the URL which is equal to `SheetName` or `sheetName!A:Z`, in other words, the error states that your request exceeds grid limits so you have to define a smaller grid, e.g. `GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/Sheet1!A1:C5`.

As a suggestion I encourage you to take a look at the examples in the documentation.